# Jquery Validate if field contains a comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been looking around but can't find a way to do this.  I really like the jquery validate script and I was wondering if there was a way to check to see if a field contains a comma and not validate if there is no comma.

Comment: If you post your code, we can help you to integrate a solution into your code.

Comment: You want to bypass validation if the field does not contain a comma?

Comment: Can you tell us which jQuery validate script you're referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.inArray()` method as it is described [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)
You should split your string, and then you can use this:
`var found = $.inArray(',', categories)`
`if(found == -1) alert("Error!")`

Answer (score 0):

not familiar with jquery validate but str.indexOf returns the position where something appears in a string, -1 means it doesnt. check a string for a comma like this :

```
if (yourString.indexOf(',') > -1) {
    validate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the jquery validate plugin:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    },
    "Please check your input."
);

$("#input").rules("add", { regex: "," })
```